# Auto increment using serial variable

Tags: 7, database

In this code i want to incerment the value by 4 and not by one . 
How Can i do it ?

```
    select_id' => array(
          'description' => 'TODO: please describe this field!',
          'type' => 'serial',
          'not null' => TRUE,
       ),
```

Comment: it would be helpful to know where this code was intended for

Comment: Sure its for unit (phpunit) testing using a separate test database in Drupal7 . This is a few lines  of my .install file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto-incrementing by a value other than one is not an easy task. [Drupal's Schema](https://drupal.org/node/146939) API allows you to supply the mysql_suffix property to supply mysql specific properties as explained in [this comment](https://drupal.org/comment/2726610#comment-2726610).

The problem is that there is no mysql TABLE CREATE option which allows you to change the auto increment amount. There is a MySQL variable [auto_increment_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) but it can only be set globally.

In this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308438/mysql-auto-increment-increment) a solution has been posted using MySQL triggers. AFAIK this is the  best SQL solution that exists.

The best solution would probably to find a way to not need to auto_increment with a value other than one or use an INTEGER type and do the incrementation manually through PHP.